# Config apple-app-site-association file with wordpress

Tags: php

I’m trying to implement iOS Universal Links, I need to serve an apple-app-association file at the root of my WordPress.

How could I serve my apple-app-association file with `application/json` content type in WordPress?

I tried to directly upload it, but it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to read about it, and I am not sure why is there anything unique about adding such a file for wordpress. what is the wordpress specific aspect here that is not just a webserver configuration that is not related to wordpress and therefor better asked on stack overflow?

Comment: Note that this was also asked and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390443/config-apple-app-site-association-file-with-wordpress

Answer (score 2):

OP moved this question to StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399792/6471228

Answer via [Alex Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394680/alex-bauer):

> Since the apple-app-site-association file is not a WordPress file, you
>   have to configure the content type at the server level. This is
>   different depending on environment (Apache vs. nginx, for example).
>   This can be hard, if your host doesn't allow access to low level
>   configuration.
>
> ### Apache configuration
>
> Modify the
>   `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` (or equivalent) file to
>   include the snippet:
>
> `<Directory /path/to/root/directory/> ... <Files
>   apple-app-site-association> Header set Content-type
>   "application/pkcs7-mime" </Files> </Directory>`
>
> ### nginx configuration
>
> Modify the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl.example.com` (or equivalent)
>   file to include the location /apple-app-assocation snippet:
>
> `server {    ...    location /apple-app-site-association {
>         default_type application/pkcs7-mime;    } }`
>
> Source: https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1#modifying-the-content-type
>
> In theory I believe it is possible to do the Apache configuration via
>   a .htaccess file, but I've never tried.